# Cant find a suitable Firebase UI version

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, firebaseui

I need to get access to Firebase UI but I can't find a proper version of it without receiving an error that I mix versions with the support Library or an error with support of my current Firebase version

Here is my gradle Code

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "il.co.appschool.firebasechatapp"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

My google services version is 3.1.0

What advice can you give me with this version fest?

Answer (score 1):

Change those:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
```

then add firebaseui:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

check this:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries